# Intercepting ClassCastException's in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a lot of code using and expecting java.util.Date which I would like to migrate to org.joda.time.LocalDate. The problem is that most of the code is dynamically typed.

So I wonder if there is any groovy way to intercept the ClassCastException, do the conversion at runtime (instead of letting the exception bubble up) and log the operation (so I could fix the code).

Example:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate

def someMethod(date) {
    println date.year()
}

// this call is ok
someMethod(new LocalDate())

// this call raises an exception
someMethod(new Date())
```

I don't want to modify the code above, like surrounding the second call with a try-catch and recalling with the right type. I wanted a way to do this globally.

Comment: if 2.0 use @Typed to prevent such things happen

Comment: Can you post some snippets of code?

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1:**

You can benefit from Groovy multimethods: you write a method overload for the JodaTime's and let the java.util.Date method be chosen when it is a dynamic method parameter:

```
def someMethod(date) {
    println date.year()
}
```

My advice is to write in this class a overload of these methods doing the conversion:

```
def someMethod(LocalDate date) {
    someMethod date.convertToJavaDate()
}
```

If you don't have access to that code, you can use metaprogramming.

---

**Idea 2:**

If you have a huge library, my guess is that you are better mixing JodaTime class. You will get a power benefit from duck typing. You will need to know which members from java.util.Date are called and reroute them to Joda's own methods:

```
class LocalDateMixin {
  def year() { this[Calendar.YEAR] }
}

LocalDate.metaClass.mixin LocalDateMixin
```

You can also apply the metaprogramming using [extension methods](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module).

Comment: Idea 1 may work. I would have to write and live with a hundred conversion methods, while I don't migrate all the code. A metaprogramming approach would be better I guess, I'll dig into this.

Comment: How much classes you have that will need this conversion?